# how to implement Network Reachebility status in multiple files?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using readability class to check network availability and it works fine with [this code](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=657&cpage=1#comment-81565). But in my app I am having approx 25 view that needs to check the network. I need to know that do I have to write pieces of code in every file ? or is there any way to write it once ?

In the code there is 3 methods that I have to implement to check the network status.

any good suggestions ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) application for your requirement. Provided by APPLE.

In this they have kept it under Application Delegate to be available to all the classes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah i put the implementation in app delegate, and let that deal with it accordingly. - good shout Jennis

Comment: will please explain how to implement it ? I am not getting how can I check network in multiple file !!!

Comment: @Maulik Have you dig into the demo which I have included ? It is pretty easy to understand from the code itself. Go through the sample and if unable to understand any part please leave comment. I would be happy to help.

Comment: @jennis : yes... I am using the same .h/.m Reachability file. But I am not getting how can I call those method into different class ? should I have to make them static methods as another answer suggested ?

Comment: or u r asking me to do some think like I should implement all methods in .m delegate after that by the reference of delegate object I have to call method ?

Comment: @Maulik Let me give you hint If you see in ApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching -- [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil]; You call this notification in your view controller class or wherever you want to have reachability. create - (void) updateInterfaceWithReachability: (Reachability*) curReach method in your controller to have update from notification. Hope now you get it. Still leave comment if any doubt.

Comment: check the answer i left, i don't write 'blog entries or tutorials' so it may need editing for clarity.

Comment: @jennis : ya still having doubt.. I did as u mentioned.I called the notification also created the method.but don't know what to update n how ? sorry for stupid questions but its mine first time so...

Comment: @Maulik Nevermind, Many developers fumbles many times including me. You can update availability of internet from the updateInterfaceWithReachability method. If you debug the application than notification is got from this method and accordingly it is displayed in the labels on the nib file.

Comment: @jennis : let me tell u first I have only imported .h/.m file of Reachability demo. Is it proper or have to import all files ???

Comment: @jennis : ya got it... i have implemented as u said.. but still having one problem when connection is lost then all notification get notified it means if I have implemented this notification in 5 file then it displays alert box 5 time one after another. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

here goes, import the header in the app delegate file.

in applicationDidFinishLaunching add
 `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                             selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];`

this means the appDelegate will be informed each time the reachability is changed. you need to implement the following:

add

-(void)reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note {

```
Reachability* curReach = [note object];
NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];

if(curReach == hostReach)
{
    if (netStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        //no conn

    }


    else if (netStatus !=NotReachable)
    {

        //has conn
    }

}
```

}

this is just an overview and you wont learn by just copying and pasting right, the reachability class can give you all you want to know, even they type of connection... so keep playing.

Comment: the above can be done in any class if you import the reachability header

Comment: its not like just copying and pasting but I am not getting the proper flow or it takes time for me... still m confused !

Comment: sorry, in the header i have defined a reachability object called hostReach .... in your header throw in -- 'Reachability * hostReach;

Comment: oh @Maulik - i wasn't suggesting you are copying and pasting, I was just suggesting its wise not to, else it will become alot harder to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Make a static method in Reachability class like

```
-(BOOL)isInternetReachable{
//your code to check the internet connectivity
// return yes or no
}
```

the you can use as simple as

```
if([Reachability isInternetReachable])
{
///// do ur stuff
}
else{
////show some error message
}
```